# CarPlay - CPPointOfInterestTemplate: I want to move map to centre and focus the marker when the user selects the Item from CPPointOfInterestTemplate

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps, carplay

I'm working on a CarPlay app and I want to focus the marker on map when I select any item from CPPointOfInterestTemplate.

In my app, some markers exceeds the visible area and map not showing that marker when clicking any point of interest

I searched for it and also referred apple's demo "Hoagies" and this same issue is there in apple's demo as well.

Is it possible to centre the map when selecting the point of interest from the list?

Below are attached screenshots and videos of it.

[image]

Video: https://easyupload.io/badons

Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering the same thing but my hunch is that moving the map is only possible with the map template which is only available on navigation apps.

Comment: @AdamLevy I feel the same thing